# update the json file

Tags: linux, text-processing, json

I have a `file`, actually json file. How I can add a comma to the end of every but the last line ? For example:

```
{"a":1, "b":1, "c":2}
{"a":3, "b":3, "c":1}
{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
```

What I want:

```
{"a":1, "b":1, "c":2},
{"a":3, "b":3, "c":1},
{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, the end result you want isn't valid JSON.  You'd need to wrap it in `[..]` if you want that to become valid.

Comment: I know, but I can do the wrapping manually.

Comment: End of **every** line, or **every but last** line?

Comment: second, every but last

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR > 1{print line","}{line=$0;}END{print $0}' jsonfile
```

Comment: @chaos Corrected!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed '$n;s/$/,/' file
```

- The `$n;` means if it's the last line just continue.
- Else it adds a `,` at the end of the line.
- If you add the `-i` flag (not POSIX) the file will be edited inplace.

If it must be `awk`:

```
awk 'NR>1{print p} {p=$0","}END{print}' file1
```

- Stores the content of the line in a variable `p`.
- The variable is printed, except in the last line.
- When the input comes to an end, the last line is print as it is.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the real goal here is to produce a JSON array from a stream of JSON entities.  A great tool for anything to do with JSON is

[image: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/]

The task of converting a file (say input.txt) of JSON entities to a JSON array is as simple as:

```
$ jq -s . input.txt
```

jq can also take input from STDIN.

Comment: This. `jq` is the swiss army knife for json, while most (all?) other answers fail when the task becomes more complex.

Answer (score 0):

How about in `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my $json_list; 
while ( my $json_str = <> ) { 
    push ( @$json_list, from_json ( $json_str ) );
}

print to_json ( $json_list, { pretty => 1, canonical => 1 } );
```

Takes data on `STDIN` or `myscript.pl somefilename` and takes the input you've designated, and builds a JSON array out of it.

Result:

```
[
   {
      "a" : 1,
      "b" : 1,
      "c" : 2
   },
   {
      "a" : 3,
      "b" : 3,
      "c" : 1
   },
   {
      "a" : 1,
      "b" : 2,
      "c" : 3
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure `bash`:

```
while read line
do
    echo "$line,"
done < <(head -n-1 testfile)
echo `tail -n1 testfile`
```

This script appends ',' to every line except the last,  and then prints the last line unchanged.

Comment: Whats with the last comma? It should not be printed

Comment: Description says "to the end of every line"

Comment: But, the example shows different and it is not valid json

Comment: Okay then. Updated my answer to be a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

The original file is actually [Newline delimited JSON](http://ndjson.org/) (NDJSON).

Instead of using GNU tools, I recommend installing [json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json) from NPM.

```
# say the file is test.log
$ json -f test.log -g
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 2
  },
  {
    "a": 3,
    "b": 3,
    "c": 1
  },
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
  }
]
```